# How to seperate day from acf datepicker

Tags: php, wordpress

I have advanced custom field date picker form which I need to separate the day (monday,tuesday etc).Is this possible ,if yes anyone please tell me how?

```
  <p><strong>15-2-2014 Saturday</strong></p>
```

this is my html code

Comment: using javascript or php - You want to seperate date?

Comment: date is called from acf field,how to call saturday(or any other day) from that date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If the date format is yymmdd, then the following works.

```
$date = get_field('date');


$y = substr($date, 0, 4); //Year
$m = substr($date, 4, 2); //Month
$d = substr($date, 6, 2); //date
```

Find the ACF doc: [ACF Datepicker](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/date-picker/)

Answer (score 3):

If You are using PHP then use below code:-

```
echo $dt = date("d",strtotime("15-2-2014 Saturday"));
```

this will give You **15** as output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string  = "<p><strong>15-2-2014 Saturday</strong></p>";
$string = explode(" ",preg_replace('~<[^>]+>~','',$string));
$day = $string[1];
```

**edit:**

If you are using `get_field()` to get the date and it is in the format you showed, then it's still a string. You'd do this:

```
$string  = get_field('date');
$string = explode(" ",preg_replace('~<[^>]+>~','',$string));
$day = $string[1];
```

the `preg_replace` may or may not be necessary depending on whether or not those html tags are *really* there, but it will work regardless. But if they aren't there, then it can be simplified to

```
$string  = get_field('date');
$string = explode(" ",$string);
$day = $string[1];
```

Comment: It is not a string ,I have a date that comes from wordpress backend(custom field) and from that date I need to separate the day

Comment: well uh, okay.. then what is the date actually in then? A `DateTime` object? Give an example of what it's actually in...

Comment: @akhila if you are using `get_field()` to get it, then it is a string that you have to parse.  And if it's in the format you showed, then this is the code for you